# git returns http error 307 from proxy after CONNECT

Tags: git, ubuntu

I am working on a remote ubuntu machine using ssh.

Both machines (my local machine and the server machine which I am accessing through ssh) are part of the same local network and are behind a proxy.

I am getting problems while trying to git clone a repository through HTTPS. It gives the following error - 
`fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dracula/gnome-terminal/': Received HTTP code 307 from proxy after CONNECT`

[image]

Although git clone through ssh works fine.
`HTTP 307 error code` means `Temporary Redirect` (that the requested resource has been temporarily moved to another URI), but I am not sure what this means in the given context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be related to your proxy (not to Git itself, or GitHub)

For instance, [this thread](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-checkin-msi-or-exe-file-http-code-307-er/1196256) (about TFVC, but the same idea applies for Git operations) mentioned:

> This turned out to be an issue with my company's network proxy.
>
> We use Zscalar and it was blocking the checkin due to a malware rule named "not allowed to upload/download unscannable files".
>
> We put in an exception for `dev.azure.com` and `.visualstudio.com` (for older Team Explorer clients) and the issue was resolved.